# Подключиться к БД из любого места - в функции и вне

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Вначале страницы я подключаюсь к базе данных

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bd");
```

Однако когда я использую mysql в функции, то вынужден повторно подключаться к базе, прописывая тот же код. Я решил написать функцию, в которой можно прописать параметры 1 раз (Логин, пароль)

```
function db_connect() {

return new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bd");

}

$mysqli = db_connect();
```

Как этот код можно улучшить? Как не подключаться к базе, если подключение уже есть?

Comment: Например, объявить где-нибудь переменную `$mysqli` и использовать `global $mysqli` внутри функций, где используется БД.

Answer (score 0):

Используем паттерн [Registry](http://omurashov.ru/pattern-registry/). Готовая реализация класса на PHP [тут](https://github.com/sedpro/chat_test/blob/master/class/Registry.php)

Далее делаем следующее

```
Registry::set('DBH', new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bd"));
```

И далее обращаемся к $DBH

```
$DBH = Registry::get('DBH');
$mysqli = $DBH->query(«SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE `id` = 'Moscow'»);
```

p/s И не вздумайте никогда использовать global переменные, как вам написали выше. Registry как и Singleton не идеальны т.к. при тестировании вставляют палки в колеса, но global это явная проблема с безопасностью. Не читайте гайды и примеры кода на php раньше 2016 года публикации, иначе мы еще долго не вычистим этот мусор с неправильными и неактуальными советами.